# Multiplying two tensors of the Levi-Civita type

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

How to multiply two epsilons with one another?

We know $$\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho'\sigma'}=-2(\delta^{\rho}_{\rho'}\delta^{\sigma}_{\sigma'}-\delta^\rho_{\sigma'}\delta^{\sigma}_{\rho'})$$

So if we had $$\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}$$ then this is always zero? I am confused if this is the case.

I think it is zero because it appears the first expression vanishes when we contract $\rho$ with $\rho'$ and $\sigma$ with $\sigma'$. Yet, the second expression would seem to be nonzero as it is just $(\pm 1)^2$ summed over the distinct rearrangements of $1,2,3,4$.

Comment: You should explain your notation. What are $\epsilon, \sigma, \mu, \nu, \rho, \rho', \sigma', \delta$?

Comment: $\delta $ kronocker, $\epsilon $ is the one like the levi-cevita and the rest are indices which are summed over

Comment: Not that I understand the physics behind but it seems to me that, at least if we work with canonical coordinates in a Euclidean space, there is no difference between upper and lower indices; then the result looks more like 24 than like 0..

Comment: It looks to me like your second expression is not of the form of the LHS of the first, so I don't see where the second one comes from?

Comment: by conservation of indices, you are missing a prime in the first equation's rhs.

Comment: The second expression is the same as the first since he is able to shift the indices two times over to obtain the second expression. It follows from the complete antisymmetry of the levi-civita symbol.

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics I added a sentence to your question. Please edit it if you disagree with what I said. I simply put what I thought was your confusion. I hope your question can get unholded with this edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the second contracted pair of deltas amounts to a single delta contracted which gives $4$ whereas the first amounts to the product of two contracted deltas hence $(4)(4)=16$. Thus, $-2(16-4)=-24$. I'm not sure about the source of the minus just yet.

I'll add some detail as tensor arithmetic seems unclear to some users. First, the consider: (which uses repeated index implied summation on $\mu, \nu$ on the l.h.s.)
$$\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho'\sigma'}=-2(\delta^{\rho}_{\rho'}\delta^{\sigma}_{\sigma'}-\delta^\rho_{\sigma'}\delta^{\sigma}_{\rho'}) \ \ \ \star $$
Observe, $\delta^\rho_{\sigma}\delta^{\sigma}_{\rho'} = \delta^{\rho}_{\rho'}$ as is easily verified by thinking about cases. Take $\star$ and contract $\rho$ with $\rho'$ and $\sigma$ with $\sigma'$, keeping $\rho$ and $\sigma$ as the dummy indices of summation, we obtain:
$$\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=-2(\delta^{\rho}_{\rho}\delta^{\sigma}_{\sigma}-\delta^\rho_{\rho}) \ \ \ \star \star $$
But, $\delta^\rho_{\rho} = 1+1+1+1 = 4 = \delta^{\sigma}_{\sigma}$. Hence, following $\star \star$
$$\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = -2(16-4) = -24. $$
Notice $$\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho'\sigma'} = \epsilon_{\rho'\sigma'\mu\nu}$$ hence $\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ ought to be the same as $\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\rho\sigma \mu\nu}$. To calculate the completely contracted levi-civita symbol with itself we note $\epsilon_{1234} = 1$ and then all other values follow from complete antisymmetry of $\epsilon_{ijkl}$ thus we directly calculate
$$\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}= 24.$$
As there are $24$ ways to rearrange $1,2,3,4$ into a list of $4$ numbers without repeats.

My conclusion, modulo context or some other Minkowski metric convention, the original identity is off by a sign. We should modify $\star$ to:
$$\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho'\sigma'}=2(\delta^{\rho}_{\rho'}\delta^{\sigma}_{\sigma'}-\delta^\rho_{\sigma'}\delta^{\sigma}_{\rho'}). $$